# CloudfrontGet cloudfront URL instead of Orgin URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-cloudfront

I have a domain using cloudfront in AWS.

```
+ test1.cloudfront.com(distribution) google.com(origin)
```

on browser, i type

```
"test1.cloudfront.com"
```

On my controller,i declare

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
//result: url = "google.com"; //origin url
```

How to get cloudfront url instead of origin url? pls help me!

Comment: Please use the standard `example.com` instead of a real domain name, unless the real domain name is actually yours and is the subject of the question.  Have you observed all of of the HTTP requests and responses involved in loading the page?  It sound like your origin may be returning a redirect to its own hostname at some point in the process.

Comment: Can you describe your situation a bit better? If you created a CloudFront distribution, why are you going to "test1.cloudfront.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Upon creation of an Amazon CloudFront distribution, a unique Domain Name will be assigned:
[image]

Use that Domain Name to access your service via CloudFront.